# How to calculate the correct location of a vertical NSRulerMarker?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, formula, nsscrollview

What is the correct formula for the location of an `NSRulerMarker` on a vertical `NSRulerView`, if the client view is flipped?

The situation: I have a view (let's call it the "main view") that is embedded in an `NSScrollView` with rulers, and it has subviews. The user can drag these subviews around, and while dragging, I want to indicate the current position on the rulers.

The main view is *flipped*: The zero point is top-left.

The horizontal position is pretty simple:

```
NSPoint scroll = myScrollView.documentVisibleRect.origin;
NSRect rect = mySubView.frame;
rulerMarkerDragLeft.markerLocation = rect.origin.x - scroll.x;
```

However the same method for the vertical position...

```
rulerMarkerDragTop.markerLocation = rect.origin.y - scroll.y;
```

does not work. The marker is **only** in the correct position when the scrollview has been scrolled down to the extreme bottom. For every *n points* scrolled back up, the marker location is *n points too high*. This is independent of the main view's size or the size of the visible area.

I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem; I guess there is a value I need to subtract from my result that expresses how far up the scrollview has been scrolled (or rather, how much further it *can* be scrolled down), but I don't think I can derive that value from `myScrollView.documentVisibleRect`...?

I may have overlooked something simple, but I can't find the solution.

**Edit 2022-11-02 17:17 CET**: Found the problem. I had set the `NSRulerView`s `clientView` to the contentView of the window. I am now setting it to the "main view" (ie. the view *inside* the scroll view), and now it works "automagically": I just set the marker locations to the subviews `frame`, no correction for scroll position or anything else needed.

Comment: Is the horizal marker correct if the view is scrolled horizontally? Have you tried `rulerMarkerDragTop.markerLocation = rect.origin.y`?

Comment: Yes, horizontal works fine. `rulerMarkerDragTop`would need to be at ...origin.y + ...size.height, remember the view is flipped. But both variante exhibit(ed) the problem. But I have found the culprint now, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple: the ruler views' `clientView` needs to be set to the view that is **inside** the scroll view, not the main content view of the window.

The positioning of the ruler markers is now very straightforward: you just use the local coordinates inside the view, ie. the subviews' `frame` values.

No correction for scroll position, view height or such necessary.

My mistake was assigning the window's main content view as the rulers' `clientView`.